# Delphi embedding localized DLL data to EXE

Tags: delphi, merge, localization

From Delphi compiler (10.x) I got both app.exe and app.enu files.
The app.enu file contains localized english strings that is indeed a DLL with STRING and RCDATA sections.
App.exe loads the STRING and RCDATA sections from app.enu with a simple call of

```
LoadLibraryEx(FileName, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
```

I would like to merge both files (.exe + .enu/dll) and load the localized STRING and RCDATA sections in my exe app.

I have tried Ilmerge, but concerns only .NET assemblies, not regular exe/dll (or unmanaged)
I have also look around and not found any obvious solutions.

Or may be simply not something possible...?

Comment: Look at those questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=embedding+dll+inside+exe+%5Bdelphi%5D and also this https://github.com/Fr0sT-Brutal/Delphi_MemoryModule

Comment: I did already search thru stackoverflow, off course but did not find any satisfactory reply I'm sorry 
I'll look on the second link more carefully asap.

Answer (score 0):

[Soluling](https://www.soluling.com)'s I18N API makes this possible.

https://github.com/soluling/I18N

A sample about this can be found here.

https://github.com/soluling/I18N/tree/master/Samples/Delphi/VCL/SingleFileDeploy

The resource DLL is added as a custom resource. The I18N API then extracts the DLL from the EXE when you start the application.

Soluling is a paid product but the I18N API is open source.